# Threejs corrugated iron

Tags: three.js

Imagine a sheet of corrugated iron. This has a length and width. Across the width, its basically lots of fairly tight curves. A curve repeats every couple of inches for the fill width of the sheet. To represent this in threejs I have created a shape which is a lot of Bezier curves. Basically the following is repeated until I have the desired width:

```
shape.bezierCurveTo(start + adjustment, curveHeight, start + curveWidth - adjustment, curveHeight, start + curveWidth, 0);
shape.bezierCurveTo(start + curveWidth + adjustment, -curveHeight, start + 2 * curveWidth - adjustment, -curveHeight, start + 2 * curveWidth, 0);
```

I then use ExtrudeGeometry to create a geometry:

```
var extrudeSettings = {
            steps: 1,
            amount: this.length,
            bevelEnabled: false,
            bevelThickness: 0,
            bevelSize: 0,
            bevelSegments: 0
        };


let wallGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);
```

But its slow. It obviously generates a lot of points. It's a very smooth curve though. Is there a setting I can use to reduce the points it uses in the curve to make it  less smooth? That would reduce the overall number of triangles and speed things up.

The only other alternative I can think of is to use a texture which looks like the light/shadow of the curves. The problem with this is that it will only look good at one angle. As I rotate my structure the light/shadow won't change. When I use the ExtrudeGeometry it has the correct shadows and it looks beautiful.

What is interesting is that once the structure is fully drawn I can rotate and zoom in/out and it all works well. So it's obviously the number of points it has to work with initially that is causing the problem.

Any suggestions on how to speed up?

Comment: For example, you can use [`curveSegments`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry) in `extrudeSettings`.

Comment: @prisoner849 that has definitely helped. Still not going to be fast enough for what I need though. Think its just a case of too many polygons :-(

Comment: Could you create a working live example? jsfiddle, codepen.

Comment: @prisoner849 not easily. The code gets fairly complicated. I; also using threeCSG to cut parts out of it. That is also contributing to issue. If you want to put your original comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: For better understanding, you could provide a picture of your "corrugated iron" :)

Comment: Maybe a simple plane with a bump map? A bump map similar to [this](https://2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/simple_faded_lines.html) maybe.

Comment: Sample here: https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApqWjFlAAjqGqlMF60rFWh6kdogP

Comment: @2pha yes that was my second option I mentioned in my question. It sort of works but as you can see when the cube rotates, the shadow doesn't change to reflect the change angle to the light as it does when done as an extruded shape. So it's definitely an option, just not one I would like to use...yet. EDIT: Just looking at your example closer and I see its a shader which is a better option than a texture, so if I do choose to go that at, will be checking the code more closely.

Comment: The shadow would change if the texture was applied to the bump or normal channel rather than the diffuse/map channel. The benefits of using a bump map is that it can be applied without using more verts so a simple plane with only 4 verts will work. The downside is that when viewing the edge, you will be able to see it is just a straight plane.

Comment: @2pha that's good to know. Right at the moment I'm going to go with prisoner849's answer as it better suits my purpose with some other stuff I know is coming up. But if performance does end up  being a problem I will definitely be investigating this option. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: glad to help, prisoner849's answer certainly seem to be what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides of using `curveSegments` of `extrudeSettings`, you can deform a thin box geometry:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 2, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, .5));

var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, .125, 50, 1, 1);
geom.vertices.forEach(function(v){
  v.z += Math.sin(v.x * Math.PI * 2) * .125;
});
geom.computeFaceNormals();
geom.computeVertexNormals();

var corrugated = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "silver"}));
scene.add(corrugated);


render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Or use the solution from 2pha.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Two benefits: 1) I can deform AFTER I have done my cutouts using threeCSG. This means they are just working on basic boxes so that is heaps faster and 2) the deform is just faster anyway.  I have some other profile shapes to consider as well and I can see how they can be done with that function. Thanks so much!